# Mono Develop error can't open .git/config

Tags: c#, git, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm using Git for a repo for my Unity 3D project. And I edited the .git/config to add unityyamlmerge to merge scenes. Afterwards, the Mono Develop messed up and showed this error:

> An error has occured Error in text editor extension chain
>
> Details: System.ArgumentException: Repository config file
>   D:\BitBucket\Queue.git\config invalid Cannot read file
>   D:\BitBucket\Queue.git\config    at
>   NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.LoadConfig() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit\BaseRepositoryBuilder.cs:line
>   904    at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.GetConfig() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit\BaseRepositoryBuilder.cs:line
>   872    at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.GuessWorkTreeOrFail() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit\BaseRepositoryBuilder.cs:line
>   918    at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.SetupWorkTree() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit\BaseRepositoryBuilder.cs:line
>   833    at NGit.BaseRepositoryBuilder`2.Setup() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit\BaseRepositoryBuilder.cs:line
>   745    at NGit.Storage.File.FileRepository..ctor(FilePath gitDir) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit.Storage.File\FileRepository.cs:line
>   114    at NGit.Storage.File.FileRepository..ctor(String gitDir) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\external\ngit\NGit\NGit.Storage.File\FileRepository.cs:line
>   130    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.LocalGitRepository..ctor(String path)
>   in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\GitRepository.cs:line
>   1578    at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitRepository..ctor(FilePath
>   path, String url) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\GitRepository.cs:line
>   73    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitVersionControl.GetRepositoryReference(FilePath
>   path, String id) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\GitVersionControl.cs:line
>   61    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitVersionControl.GetRepositoryReference(FilePath
>   path, String id) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\GitVersionControl.cs:line
>   65    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitVersionControl.GetRepositoryReference(FilePath
>   path, String id) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git\GitVersionControl.cs:line
>   65    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepositoryReference(String
>   path, String id) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\VersionControlService.cs:line
>   199    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlService.GetRepository(IWorkspaceObject
>   entry) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\VersionControlService.cs:line
>   185    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlFileSystemExtension.GetRepository(FilePath
>   path) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\VersionControlFileSystemExtension.cs:line
>   29    at
>   MonoDevelop.VersionControl.VersionControlFileSystemExtension.CanHandlePath(FilePath
>   path, Boolean isDirectory) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\MonoDevelop.VersionControl\VersionControlFileSystemExtension.cs:line
>   20    at MonoDevelop.Core.FileService.GetFileSystemForPath(String
>   path, Boolean isDirectory) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Core\MonoDevelop.Core\FileService.cs:line
>   283    at MonoDevelop.Core.FileService.RequestFileEdit(String
>   fileName) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Core\MonoDevelop.Core\FileService.cs:line
>   246    at
>   MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorView.CheckReadOnly(Int32 line) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor\SourceEditorView.cs:line
>   1021    at Mono.TextEditor.TextEditorData.CanEdit(Int32 line) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\Mono.Texteditor\Mono.TextEditor\TextEditorData.cs:line
>   501    at Mono.TextEditor.EditMode.InsertCharacter(UInt32 unicodeKey)
>   in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\Mono.Texteditor\Mono.TextEditor\EditMode.cs:line
>   115    at Mono.TextEditor.SimpleEditMode.HandleKeypress(Key key,
>   UInt32 unicodeKey, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\Mono.Texteditor\Mono.TextEditor\SimpleEditMode.cs:line
>   421    at Mono.TextEditor.TextArea.SimulateKeyPress(Key key, UInt32
>   unicodeChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\Mono.Texteditor\Mono.TextEditor\Gui\TextArea.cs:line
>   913    at
>   MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.SourceEditorWidget.MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.ITextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor\SourceEditorWidget.cs:line
>   144    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.DocFood.DocFoodTextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\MonoDevelop.DocFood\MonoDevelop.DocFood\DocFoodTextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   63    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at
>   MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.CompletionTextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\CompletionTextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   100    at
>   MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion.CSharpCompletionTextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\CSharpBinding\MonoDevelop.CSharp.Completion\CSharpCompletionTextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   204    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at
>   MonoDevelop.CSharp.Formatting.CSharpTextEditorIndentation.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\CSharpBinding\MonoDevelop.CSharp.Formatting\CSharpTextEditorIndentation.cs:line
>   357    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at
>   MonoDevelop.Debugger.ExceptionCaughtTextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\MonoDevelop.Debugger\MonoDevelop.Debugger\ExceptionCaughtDialog.cs:line
>   439    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content.TextEditorExtension.KeyPress(Key
>   key, Char keyChar, ModifierType modifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Content\TextEditorExtension.cs:line
>   109    at
>   MonoDevelop.SourceEditor.ExtensibleTextEditor.ExtensionKeyPress(Key
>   key, UInt32 ch, ModifierType state) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\d478831d940d36a4\monodevelop\main\src\addins\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor2\MonoDevelop.SourceEditor\ExtensibleTextEditor.cs:line
>   249

So what did I do wrong here? How do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you  post your **.git\config** please?  Also what happens if you revert your change to the **config**?

Comment: Nevermind. I've managed to solve it myself by disabling Tools->Add-in Manager->Version Control->Git support. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.

I've managed to solve it myself by disabling **Tools->Add-in Manager->Version Control->Git support**.

Thanks anyway.